# WDF Progress bar incrementing by odd number and looping

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I have a progress bar with a min of 0 and max of 100. If I increment it by 33 it will end at 99/100 but then when I loop it it tries to add 33 to the 99 and I get Out of Bounds exception even though I set the value of the progress bar back to 0 after every loop. Can anyone suggest a solution around this?

```
    private void WorkProgress1(int progress)
    {

       pbProgress.Value = progress;
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {

        if (_progress == 100) { _progress = 0; }
        int Increment = (100 / count);
            _progress += (Increment);
            WorkProgress1(_progress);

    }
```

Comment: You only set `_progress` to 0 if `_progress` is exactly 100. 99 + 33 is not 100.

Comment: What value does `count` have? Is it 3?

Comment: Could you tell me a way I can work around it? Count is dependant on how many items I have so it could be anything. I was just giving an example of 3 though sorry. I understand that the exception could occur with different counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution would be to check if `_progress + increment` is more than `100` before you assign the value to `_progress`. If it is equal or more than `100` send `100` to `WorkProgress1()` and put `_progress` back to `0`.

```
private void DoWork()
{
   int increment = (100 / count);

   if(_progress + increment >= 100)
   {
      WorkProgress1(100);
      _progress = 0;
   }
   else
   {
      _progress += (increment);
      WorkProgress1(_progress);
   }
}
```

Comment: If I had a count of 2 it shoots my progess bar to 100% after the first one instead of doing 50% + 50%.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I updated my answer. Now it should work.

Comment: Haha thanks. Some reason when my count is 3 it doesnt give me the error anymore but sometimes it increments weird.. maybe it's my code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is more compact croxy's solution:

```
private void DoWork()
{
    int increment = (100 / count);
    _progress = Math.Min(100, _progress + increment);
    WorkProgress1(_progress);
    _progress %= 100;
}
```